# Symfony2 Custom SessionBag not saving multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, forms, symfony, session

I have a simple Auction listing form with pictures uploader. I have created a custom SessionBag to store picture URLs for pictures uploaded by a plupload Javascript uploader which are uploaded before a form is submitted so that upon the persisting of the data the picture URLs for the uploaded files could be fetched from the session and added to the entity. To prevent collisions of the data if the use decides to open more than one tab with the auction form I am using the CSRF token of the form as identifier key in the pictures array in the session bag to reference the picture URLs. For some reason, however, it doesn't save the pictures with the token given as a array key. It only saves the picture URLs if I save them into the array without the key.

Here is the code of the SessionBag:

```
class UploadedPicturesAttributeBag implements SessionBagInterface
{

const DEFAULT_INDEX = 'default';

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $pictures = array();

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getName()
{
    return Constants\Session::UPLOADED_PICTURES_BAG;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function initialize(array &$array)
{
    $this->pictures[self::DEFAULT_INDEX] = &$array;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getStorageKey()
{
    return Constants\Session::UPLOADED_PICTURES_BAG;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function clear()
{
    $this->pictures = null;
}

/**
 * @param string $index
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function clearIndex($index = null)
{
    if (array_key_exists($index, $this->pictures)) {
        $this->pictures[$index] = null;
    }

    $this->pictures[self::DEFAULT_INDEX] = null;
}


/**
 * @param string $index
 *
 * @return array|bool
 */
public function getPictures($index = null)
{
    if (null === $index) {
        return $this->pictures[self::DEFAULT_INDEX];
    }

    if (array_key_exists($index, $this->pictures)) {
        return $this->pictures[$index];
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * @param string $index
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasPictures($index = null)
{
    if (null === $index) {
        return count($this->pictures[self::DEFAULT_INDEX]) > 0;
    }

    return count($this->pictures[$index]) > 0;
}

/**
 * @param string $pictureName
 * @param string $index
 */
public function addPicture($pictureName, $index = null)
{
    if (null === $index && !in_array($pictureName, $this->pictures[self::DEFAULT_INDEX], true)) {
        $this->pictures[self::DEFAULT_INDEX][] = $pictureName;
    }

    if (!in_array($pictureName, $this->pictures[$index], true)) {
        $this->pictures[$index][] = $pictureName;
    }
}
}
```

In the controller which handles the upload I get the registered session bag from the container and call the addPicture method with the name and the csrf token. When I dump the bag on the next page it shows the array as empty. If I use the addPicture method without the second argument it works but then I cannot use the collision technique to prevent mixing of picture from different forms.

Any idea what is wrong with the session bag or my approach at the problem?